# How to Split Array that is Declared Global

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have an array that consist of First Name _ Last Name so they would read like so
Michael_Jordan
Javier_Lopez
George_Jones

I have an loop set-up to iterate through each of these, but I only want to take what's after the "*"  The problem I have is that the array was declared globally, and it is declared in far to many places for me to change.  If I try to use the .Split function I receive an error of System.Array does not contain a definition for split.  What is another option to take the data after the "*" in the array?

```
public static string GetEmployees()
{
    string queryString = "select employeeName from tbl_GlobalEmployeeData where state = 'AL';
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.MyConnectionString.ConnectionStrings[0]);
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "_" + reader[1].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "_" + reader[1].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore = tempList.ToArray();
        for (int q = AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetLowerBound(0); q <= AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
        {
            return AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore[q];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

```
for (int q = AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetLowerBound(0); q <= AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
   //This line is where I get the error mentioned above
   string lastName = AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.Split('_')[1];
}
```

Comment: I can't see a connection between your question and the code. Have you pasted the wrong snippet?

Comment: After the `""`? After the nothing? What are you talking about? Do you mean to split on the underscore? Please show the code for your global array and clarify what exactly you're trying to do with examples. Also, you can't use `Split` on an array. That's a method for `String`. You need to use `Split` on the individual strings in your array.

Comment: Apology to the 2 that have attempted to help, I did post the wrong code snippet.  Please look at the code posted in my edit.

Comment: Still a lot of unanswered questions. Can't answer your question until you respond to them.

Comment: I want to split the array - So for example it reads Javier_Lopez I want to take Lopez from the array.

Comment: Again, you can't use split on an array. It is a method for a string.

Comment: Wow, what alternative do I have to only capture the data after the underscore?  I posted the SQL that is run to pull the employee names directly from a SQL Server table

Comment: On a side note, your GetEmployees method appears to be flawed; it always returns the first element of ThisStore, ignoring the rest of the employees (assuming that ThisStore is a collection of employee names.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is "I want to split the array - So for example it reads Javier_Lopez I want to take Lopez from the array"

Very easy:

```
string last = yourString.Split(new char[] { '_' })[1];
```

Again, you seem to be using this on an array which is why you are getting that error. You need to iterate through your array and do this on each individual string in your array.

EDIT: To modify the array and leave only last names, try this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string s in stringArray)
{
    stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].Split(new char[] { '_' })[1];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: How would I do this to each name that is being returned in the array?  I follow what you are saying to do, just not grasping how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Split` on strings. So you could do something like this:

```
List<string> lastNames = new List<string>();
for (int q = AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetLowerBound(0); q <= AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
   string lastName = AllCompanyEmployees.State.ThisStore[q].Split('_')[1];
   lastNames.Add(lastName);
}
```

At the end you would have a `List<string>` with all last names of your employees. With that you can continue to work.